# When is definition of class' static data member (un/-)necesary

Tags: c++, static, c++14, undefined-reference

I have a big project and work on refactoring it. Major task is rewrite of logger. New logger is (as far as I can tell) API-compatible with old one, so I believed that after changing header include directory, recompile and relink everything should work. But no. I get multiple errors of the kind `undefined reference to <static_data_member>`. I can't paste actual code, but it looks for example like this:

```
// Foo.h
class Foo {
    static const int bar = 0;
    int baz; // assigned in c-tor
    void updateBaz() { baz = bar; }
    // ....
}
```

`static const int bar` is NOT defined in Foo.cpp. It is sometimes printed by log macros. And it used to work (with old logger), now I have to define it. What change could have caused it?

Another example that that occurs with variables declared by boost:

```
(...)/blog_adaptor.h:50: error: undefined reference to bbost::serialization::version<CA::CReyzinSignature>::value'
```

So: when are definitions to static members required and when can they be omitted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: "_I can't paste actual code, but it looks for example like this_" We **don't** require actual code. What we do require is manufactured [mcve]. So, please provide an example for both cases, so we could tell what is different between them.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I perhaps not said it clearly: I do understand that defining is necessary. I was more surprised that sometimes it isn't. That question doesn't answer why/when it isn't

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I know, but to produce such example I would have to understand the difference between two usages of the member by both loggers and probably knew the whole answer by then.

Comment: @MateuszL That's the whole purpose of [mcve]. Chances are, that you may solve the issue on your own, by the time you are able to produce it. How do you expect us to answer such a question, without having necessary information, such as the differences between the cases?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I hoped that there is some universal C++ rule saying "if conditions A, B, C are met, definition of static data member may/must be omitted".

Comment: @MateuszL Self-research is not a vice :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the variables are declared `inline` (a C++17 feature), definitions of static member variables are not *optional*, as far as the C++ standard is concerned. Failure to provide a definition is undefined behavior.

Compilers and linkers may vary on exactly what will *make* them check to see if definitions exist, but that is the nature of undefined behavior.

Comment: Isn't `constexpr int bar = 10;` another exception, even before C++17?

Comment: @MSalters: [Not according to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static): "*If a const non-inline static data member or a constexpr static data member is odr-used, a definition at namespace scope is still required*" It's only C++17 that makes `constexpr` static members implicitly `inline` and therefore not require a definition.

Comment: @cpplearner: Well, you *could* remember the various rules of "odr-use". Or you could just remember that non-`inline` static members require definitions.

Comment: But why do you think `inline` variables do not require definitions?

Comment: @cpplearner: I'm not sure I understand the question. `inline` variables don't require definitions because that's *exactly why the feature was invented*: to allow people to write global/class static variables without writing separate definitions for them.

Comment: It seems that you don't think `static inline int bar = 0;` is a definition. OK fine.

Comment: @cpplearner: Or that when I said "separate definitions", I actually meant *separate*.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I didn't expect it to be UB, so didn't research topics around ODR deep enough. Now I managed to find minimal example that illustrates my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As Nicol Bolas answered, the code in my project had undefined behavior because static data members were initialized but nowhere defined. To summarize and extend:
Static data member doesn't need to be defined when:

- It is not used or is used only in discarded branches (non-instantiated templates and discarded branches of constexpr-if)
- in C++17 if member is inline
- also clang-tidy says that "out-of-line definition of constexpr static data member is redundant in C++17 and is deprecated", so probably static constexpr also doesn't need it

Further, following code shows why my bad project was not triggering linker error before. I don't know whether it is "not odr-use" or "Undefined Behavior that doesn't hurt you yet":

```
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>
class Klass {};
//BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Klass, 3);
// would be expanded to:
namespace boost { namespace serialization {
template<>
struct version<Klass> {
    static const int value = 3; // not defined anywhere
};
} }

int foo (int val) { // was used by old logger
    return val;
}
int bar (const int &val) { // is used by new logger
    return val;
}
int main () {
//    return bar(boost::serialization::version<Klass>::value); // link error
    return foo(boost::serialization::version<Klass>::value); // works fine
}
```

So there is no link error if member is used but not it's address is not queried. Passing value by reference qualifies as querying the address.